# Setting a javascript date to be static

Tags: javascript, date, static

How can i make this code to give me a static date?Like if I post something on *10 december 2015 at 15:03 2015* to show that date,not the current date.

```
        var d = new Date();
var months = new Array ("Ianuarie","Februarie", "Martie","Aprilie","Mai","Iunie","Iulie","August","Septembrie","Octombrie","Noiembrie","Decembrie");
var day = d.getUTCDay();
var  month = months[d.getUTCMonth()];
var hour = d.getUTCHours();
var year = d.getUTCFullYear();
if(hour < 10) {
    hour = "0" + hour;
}
var minutes = d.getUTCMinutes();
if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
}
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = ("Postat pe " + day + " " + month + " la ora " + hour + ":" +  minutes + " | " + year ).toString();
```

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this(e.g if your date is "10/10/2004"):

```
var d = new Date("10/10/2004")
```